# Flutter show GetX snackbar fails with GoRouter

Tags: flutter, dart, get, snackbar, flutter-go-router

I am using the [go_router](https://gorouter.dev/) in my app and also the [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package. The problem is that since I implemented the `Go-Router` I can no longer show the `Get.snackbar`. It is failing and throwing a `null-error`.

For the `GoRouter` to work I had to add the `.router` for my `GetMaterialApp`. And then `navigationKey` was no longer available so I tried it with only `key`.

This is my `GetMaterialApp`:

```
  child: GetMaterialApp.router(
    title: 'Wishlists',

    key: Get.key, // <- I think that this might cause the issue

    routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
    routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
    routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
    translationsKeys: AppTranslation.translationsKeys,
    locale: locale,
    fallbackLocale: fallbackLocale,

  ),
```

This is the `error`:

> Error: Unexpected null value.
> at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:51492/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
> at Object.nullCheck (http://localhost:51492/dart_sdk.js:5399:30)
> at [_configureOverlay] (http://localhost:51492/packages/get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart.lib.js:2970:53)
> at [_show] (http://localhost:51492/packages/get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart.lib.js:3113:30)

I feel like it has something to do with the `key` inside the `GetMaterialApp`, but I have no idea how to solve this.

Is this a known bug? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you implement the class `GoRouter` as router you lose the context which is in `Get.context` and without the context `Get.snackbar` cannot work anymore.

As a work around I pass the context in parameter to my controller (or anywhere you need the context)

Ex:

```dart
class GoRouterPages {
  static final router = GoRouter(
      debugLogDiagnostics: true,
      initialLocation: 'test',
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
            path: '/test',
            name: 'test',
            builder: RouterTools.globalContextBinder( // globalContextBinder code below
              (context, state) {
                LoginBinding().dependencies();
                return const LoginView();
              },
            )),
      ]);
}

class RouterTools {
  static GoRouterWidgetBuilder globalContextBinder(GoRouterWidgetBuilder? goRouterWidgetBuilder) {
    callback(context, state) {
      // Here we can put every global controller/provider that needs the go_router context !
      if (Get.isRegistered<RootController>() == false) {
        Get.lazyPut(() => RootController(context: context));
      }

      return goRouterWidgetBuilder!(context, state);
    }

    return callback;
  }
}

// Then in RootController you can open a snackbar like this
    const snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('My snackbar'),
    );

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context!).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```